# SQL update flag where distinct values

Tags: mysql, sql

Given the fallowing table mytable sample:

```
+------+------+
| code | flag |
+------+------+
|  111 |    0 |
|  222 |    0 |
|  111 |    1 |
|  111 |    1 |
|  333 |    1 |
|  333 |    1 |
|  333 |    1 |
|  444 |    1 |
+------+------+
```

I want to write a SQL query that will update flag = 0 where flag = 1 and code is distinct so it will result the fallowing output:

```
+------+------+
| code | flag |
+------+------+
|  111 |    0 |
|  222 |    0 |
|  111 |    0 |
|  111 |    1 |
|  333 |    0 |
|  333 |    1 |
|  333 |    1 |
|  444 |    0 |
+------+------+
```

What I tried:

```
SET @codeid =( SELECT DISTINCT code FROM mytable WHERE flag = 1);
UPDATE mytable SET flag = 0 WHERE code IN (@codeid);
```

Problem is that @codeid expects 1 single value and I will get more throwing this:

> Subquery returns more than 1 row

What I will need to modify in order to be able to update more codes flag?

Comment: Use COUNT instead.

Comment: Is there any criteria to chose which one of the bunch has to be unflagged?

Comment: 333 is not distinct... why aren't all rows set to 0?

Comment: @SalmanA there are 3 entries with code 333 and flag =1, so I want to keep only one of them having at the end only 1 distinct value with flag =0.

Comment: @Sterconium No, there isn't any criteria.

Comment: jarlh The problem is setting that variable @codeid that can have 1 single value (entry).

Comment: I think you attempt to return `@codeid` as `(111,333,44)` , is that correct? If so, you can use `GROUP_CONCAT`. However I've tested with `IN (@codeid)` and it doesn't work like `IN (111,333,444)` .. so..

Comment: do you have an index - or something that could be used to distinguish one row from the other?

Comment: @bt19 do you have any id in table

Comment: @tcadidot0 yes that correct, SET codeid expects a single value only like just for example (111). Isn't any other way around this ?

Comment: @Lutz and Yasin, yes, I have a auto increment id that is unique for each entry. lets assume: 1,2,3 ... 8.

Comment: Can you modify the table and/or define new ones?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  Your question seems to presuppose that there is an ordering.

Let me assume that you have a column that specifies the ordering.  If so, you can do:

```
update mytable t join
       (select code, min(<ordercol>) as min_ordercol,
               sum(flag = 0) as num_zeros
        from mytable t
        group by code
       ) tt
       on t.code = tt.code
    set t.flag = 0
    where num_zeros = 0 and <ordercol> = min_ordercol;
```

If you don't have such a column, you can add one using `alter table`.

Comment: what means "tt" (under GROUP BY) ? From your query? It is the table name ?

Comment: @bt19 . . . It is a table alias that names the subquery (which is also called a *derived table*).

Comment: Got it, but in your query I can't see where you use the actual table name: mytable

Comment: because he already assign `mytable` with alias `t`. So instead `mytable.code` its just `t.code`. There are two aliases being assigned here. Some people assign alias as such e.g `mytable AS t` or for the sub-query `... ) AS tt` but without `AS`, it should work as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try using Row Number concept

```
UPDATE Y 
SET flag = 0
FROM mytable Y JOIN
     (
       SELECT t.code, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY code ORDER BY code) row_num,
       FROM mytable t CROSS JOIN 
     ) X ON X.code = Y.code AND X.row_num > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have id in same table you can try this query :

```
SET @codeid =( SELECT id FROM mytable WHERE flag = 1 GROUP BY code);
UPDATE mytable SET flag = 0 WHERE id IN (@codeid);
```

OR

```
UPDATE mytable SET flag = 0 WHERE id IN ( SELECT id FROM mytable WHERE flag = 1 GROUP BY code );
```

Comment: No, with group by it will return first id of each group

Comment: I think you forgot min() : `UPDATE mytable SET flag = 0 WHERE id IN ( SELECT min(id) FROM mytable WHERE flag = 1 GROUP BY code );`

Comment: We can use min or order by , but here i dont think there is need of it, it will take first record from group